# How can i sort my arraylist alphabetical

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, arraylist, alphabetical

I want to sort my arraylist alphabetical but I don't get it...maybe you can help me. I dont know why but i cant work with collections.sort...what am i coding wrong?
 thanks a lot for all your help and time, Vinzenz

```
public class SongsManager {

    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
    private String mp4Pattern = ".mp4";
    private String MP3Pattern = ".MP3";
    private String MP4Pattern = ".MP4";
    private String m4aPattern = ".m4a";

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager() {

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;



    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(mp4Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(MP4Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(MP3Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(m4aPattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that shows your problem.

Comment: write a comparator class for sortin your arrylist they way you want to sort it

Comment: How are you going to sort it? Could you post some example of input and expected output? Also you can't sort inside HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collections.sort`

```
Collections.sort(listOfStrings, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

See the following for details:

[String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

You can also create a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), instead of using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`

Comment: I dont know why, but it doesnt work for me...can you show me exactly what i have to do transferred to my example?...i really dont get it :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own `Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>` and pass it to `Collections.sort`.